# Detecting/Listing variable declarations in C

Tags: c, variables, gcc

I would like to list all the variables that have been declared in my C program for analysis. Is there an easy way I can do this? I would think that building a lexer just for this purpose would be cumbersome. Is there another way?

Well, I think I have to be more clear :-). I intend to analyse a lot of C files using a C library that I intend to write, which needs to have this functionality. Hence, it'd be great if I can do this using C (since it can integrate with my library). However I can pre-process in any other language as well. But it'd increase dependencies.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?  Determining the location and size of non-stack variables is easy enough by examining objdump or linker output for the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cscope (http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) can identify and index all symbols in your program and has a command line mode to query the symbol database from command line or GUI tools.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to write a pretty powerful parser anyway, if you want to handle typedefs and so on.  You might want to look at using [clang/llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/) - you can probably modify it to output the data you want pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the job properly requires a significant chunk of the C preprocessor and a lexical analyzer, which is quite a lot of a C compiler.

Doing the job ad hoc is easier - but you get to choose how ad hoc you're going to be.

Comment: The usual meaning of _ad hoc_ is Latin 'for this', meaning 'formed, arranged, or done for a particular purpose only'. So, rather than doing the job with a full-scale C preprocessor and lexical analyzer, you can (if you so wish) do a 'sufficiently good' job by doing things like: only recognize built-in types and types with an explicit prefix such as `struct xxx` or `union yyy` or `enum zzz`.  This sometimes gets you quite a lot of your variables; more often, it misses a lot. You then think about adding `www_t` (recognizing the `_t` suffix). And you worry about `FILE`, etc. That's _ad hoc_.